# static cms generator in C or shell or PHP with multilingual support via gettext

Tags: cms, localization

I am looking for

- static cms generator in C or shell or PHP
- with multilingual support via gettext.
- The page source in markdown.
- This will be hosted on a UNIX.
- The sysadmin wishes to not install Python or Go or Ruby or an SQL database.
- One of the requirements also is no JavaScript and
- freedom-respecting (GNU GPL, MIT, etc).

I checked https://staticsitegenerators.net/ but it didn't seem fruitful, http://qgoda.net only has docker instructions and I don't have docker.

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try [qgoda](https://github.com/gflohr/qgoda), but without Docker, you can still install it from the source code. It seems to be written in Perl (and lots of Javascript which you apparently don't want...?)

Check out the Perl source code with `git clone`. If you are lucky, qgoda will run as-is.  It is more likely that you still need to run `perl Makefile.PL` . And even that will not run successfully without certain one-off setup tasks. I mean, if you never have worked with Perl before, you probably have to set up cpanm (CPANminus) , the Perl package manager (similar to dpkg, apt, npm, ...) by answering a few questions about your preferences ("Install as root y/n ?, etc.)

Comment: Hello @knb, thank you for your reply! 'perl Makefile.PL' asks to install yarn and npm, neither or which I would like to have, as I would prefer to not add nodejs or C# to the mix.